# AppCompatButton on Android 5: app:backgroundTint works but supportBackgroundTintList does NOT :(

Tags: android, button, android-appcompat

I need to reuse XML layout and change button color programmatically.
In Android 5 applying `app:backgroundTint` in XML changes button color but I need to do it programmatically and I do it `in Recyclerview`:

```
holder.button.supportBackgroundTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, backgroundColorRes)
```

This has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setSupportBackgroundTintList()` method is annotated with `@RestrictTo({Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP})`, which means you are not supposed to call it directly. Instead, you should use `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList()`.

Try changing your code to this instead:

```
val colorStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, backgroundColorRes)
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(holder.button, colorStateList)
```

If you look at the source code for `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList()`, you'll see that it does different things for API 21+ (Android 5 and higher) than earlier versions. Chances are good that the "support" background tint is only applied on earlier versions of Android, and `ViewCompat` will make it so that you don't have to think about that.

Comment: Thanks! Do we need to use `ViewCompat` with other setters? How do I know when I need to use it and when I can leave it out?

Comment: The short answer is to always use the non-appcompat view type (e.g. use `<Button>` instead of `<AppCompatButton>`) and then use `ViewCompat` any time the system warns you that you're trying to call a method that is only supported on certain versions. In this case, if you have a `Button` and try to call `setBackgroundTintList()` you'll get a warning: "Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19)". That's a signal that instead I should use `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList()`.

Comment: Note that when you use a `<Button>` tag in your layout, if your activity is using an AppCompat theme, it will be inflated as an `AppCompatButton` automatically. So you'll get the "right" type without having to think about it.